# How to get TeamCity to show # of ignored tests?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, msbuild, teamcity

I have a build on TeamCity with MSBuild building a .NET 4.5 solution.  MSTest running the unit tests with the bundled dotCover used for code coverage.  The build works, the unit tests run, and I get the code coverage just fine, but it only shows the # of failed tests and the # of passed tests.

How do I get it to show the # of ignored tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding an Ignore attribute or disabling test through UI removes test from the run by MSTest, i.e. no record of this test is reported in Results section of corresponding trx report. Since TeamCity MSTest processor deals only with Results section of trx file, it doesn't know that any test was disabled.

[have a look](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17667#tab=Comments)

Comment: hi Rob, could you provide an example of the paratemer that will be used. example ignoring test123